# Best way to dynamically change the width of an image view to match width of label text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm constructing a `UITableViewCell` via a nib file. I also have a corresponding `UITableViewCell` subclass which the nib's outlets are connected to.

I need a dynamically sized `UIImageView` (only the width) to be the background of my tableviewcell's label. Is there a way this can be achieved via autolayout?

I've tried setting the imageview as a subview of the label in code:

```
[theLabel sizeToFit]
CGRect boundingRect = [theLabel.text boundingRectWithSize: theLabel.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:0 context:0];
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:boundingRect];
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"validImageName"]];
[theLabel addSubview: background];
```

However this does not result in the correct frame. I've also considered setting the background of the label with `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: @"aValidImageName"];` but this does not include padding on the background image. Also, the background image contains rounded corners which I want to retain (which this method cuts). Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: did you try adding UIImageView as subview on the UILabel with auto layout?

Comment: I didn't realize that was an option, how would I go about doing that? @Rage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

1) You can use Autoresizing to change image width according to size of screen.

**(OR)**

2) Set Custom frame for your imageview

Ex:

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:(0,0,Your_Custom_Width_Size_Value,100)];
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"validImageName"]];
[theLabel addSubview: background];

                        (or)
```

//Change width according to the label

```
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:(0,0,Your_Label_Name.frame.size.width,100)];
    background.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"validImageName"]];
    [theLabel addSubview: background];
```

Comment: I was not aware of autoresizing, I looked into it and changed my approach. Thanks!

Comment: @Benjammin, All ways welcome.Thanks for response... :)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a UIView object as a container and add your UIImageView and UILabel as subViews to it. Add constraints to the Image View and the Label so that their height and width are always equal to the superview. Then just give the container UIView whatever frame you want.